Singular verb with money, distance and time

Where is that five pounds I lent you?

(NOT Where are those five pounds …?)

Twenty miles is a long way to walk.

When we talk about amounts and quantities we usually use singular determiners, verbs and pronouns, even if the noun is plural. Keeping in view the above-mentioned examples, can we say,

Five pounds is needed to buy this toy.


Thirty minutes is/has left in the match.


Yes, because those are considered as "a unit" of time or amount. But the plural is also fine.

"There is thirty minutes left of the match" - certainly not "has left".

Your first example is not incorrect, but it is very far from idiomatic. Something like Five pounds is a lot of money is fine. But the idea expressed in your example would be much more naturally expressed by native speakers as something like This toy costs five pounds, or even If you hope to buy this toy, you'll need to have five pounds at the ready.  (Yes, I understand that neither of these paraphrases makes the point in your question about whether five pounds should be treated as singular or plural.)

@PaulTanenbaum It sounds fine to me. We can think of it as "[loan of] five pounds".

Sums of money, like most measurements, are generally used as collective terms, therefore singularly. English makes a distinction between countable and non-countable nouns, and, broadly speaking, things that are measured are not countable. For example, you count bottles but you measure water (by volume).
In UK currency, a single £1 coin does exist, so you could say "can you give me those five pound coins" because the coins are countable. But the sum of £5 can exist as a single note, too, so you would say "can you give me that five-pound note". Of course, money is not always counted in cash denominations, so the sum itself should be seen as a measurement, not a count.
It is also common to make measurements into an attribute which is considered singularly. For example, we tend to refer to somebody's height this way: "he is six foot four", rather than saying he has a measured height of 6 feet and 4 inches.
There can sometimes be a choice of how you use a measured amount - plural, or as a collective term - depending on whether you are emphasising the individuality of the things collected. For example, we might say "the final miles of a marathon are the most difficult" to refer to the final approximate portion of that race; however, it wouldn't be wrong to say "those final miles..." if the miles were being individually counted.
